# Save docx as pdf in c#, fails to export excel charts properly

Tags: c#

I want to create docx files programatically. I need to include excel charts in it, and then I have to export it into pdf. I use C# 4.0 and Microsoft.Office.Interop for that.

The problem is that in the exported pdf files the 1/5 part of the charts are cut down. 
Here is an example of the problem:

[2shared.com link to the pdf file](http://www.2shared.com/document/kbcM31UD/Doksi.html)

This happens too if I try to save in xps.

If I copy and paste the excel chart in word, then it works somehow after that...

There is another problem too. The charts are randomly sized down. This depends on if the excel chart was visible during the scripting process or not (this picture is captured from word 2010, I circled the problem with red):

[image]

I create the excel charts as InlineShapes, with the AddOLEObject method, classtype: "Excel.Chart.8" . I set their size to 200x200 (wrdInlineShape.Width, wrdInlineShape.Height)

Adam said that I should include the source code. It is long, but here you go:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
app.Visible = true;
Word.Document doc = app.Documents.Open(@"D:\programozás\OHV\template.docx");
string classtype = "Excel.Chart.8";
object oEndOfDoc = "\\endofdoc";
Bookmark titleBookMark = doc.Bookmarks.get_Item("title");
titleBookMark.Range.Text = "I love OHV";

for (int xi = 1; xi <= 2; xi++)
{
    //  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range wrdRng = doc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref oEndOfDoc).Range;
    Bookmark shapeBookMark = doc.Bookmarks.get_Item("shape" + xi );
    Bookmark subtitleBookMark = doc.Bookmarks.get_Item("title" + xi);
    subtitleBookMark.Range.Text = "Super Subject";
    Word.InlineShape wrdInlineShape = doc.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject(classtype, Range: shapeBookMark.Range);
    if (wrdInlineShape.OLEFormat.ProgID == classtype)
    {
        object verb = Word.WdOLEVerb.wdOLEVerbHide;
        wrdInlineShape.OLEFormat.DoVerb(ref verb);
        Random rn = new Random();
        Excel.Workbook obook = (Excel.Workbook)wrdInlineShape.OLEFormat.Object;
        Excel.Worksheet sheet = (Excel.Worksheet)obook.Worksheets["Sheet1"];

        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)sheet.Cells[i, 1]).Value = i + ".";
            for (int c = 2; c <= 3; c++)
            {
                ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)sheet.Cells[i, c]).Value = rn.Next(1, 5);
                ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)sheet.Cells[i, c]).Value = rn.Next(1, 5);
            }
            ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)sheet.Cells[i, 4]).Value = "";
        }

        wrdInlineShape.Width = 200;
        wrdInlineShape.Height = 200;
        Excel.Chart chart = obook.ActiveChart;
        obook.ActiveChart.ApplyLayout(9, Excel.XlChartType.xlColumnClustered);
        obook.ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Caption = "BMEVIHVA109 - Jelek és Rendszerek\n XY kurzus - Dr Erős Péter";
        obook.ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Font.Size = 6;

        chart.ChartArea.Fill.ForeColor.SchemeColor = 41;
        Console.WriteLine(chart.ChartArea.Fill.ForeColor.RGB);
        chart.ChartArea.Fill.BackColor.SchemeColor = 23;
        Console.WriteLine(chart.ChartArea.Fill.BackColor.RGB);
        chart.ChartArea.Fill.TwoColorGradient(Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoGradientStyle.msoGradientHorizontal, 1);

        obook.ActiveChart.SetSourceData(sheet.get_Range("A1", "B5"));
        obook.ActiveChart.Legend.Delete();
        chart.ChartArea.RoundedCorners = true;
        Excel.Axis axis = (Excel.Axis)chart.Axes(
        Excel.XlAxisType.xlCategory,
        Excel.XlAxisGroup.xlPrimary);
        axis.HasTitle = true;
        axis.AxisTitle.Text = "54 kérdőív";
        axis.AxisTitle.Font.Size = 6;
        axis.HasMajorGridlines = true;

        axis = (Excel.Axis)chart.Axes(
        Excel.XlAxisType.xlValue,
        Excel.XlAxisGroup.xlPrimary);
        axis.HasTitle = false;
        axis.HasMajorGridlines = true;
        axis.MaximumScale = 5;
        axis.MinimumScale = 0;
        wrdInlineShape.Width = 200;
        wrdInlineShape.Height = 200;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range tableRange = doc.Bookmarks.get_Item("table" + xi).Range;

        //  sheet.UsedRange.Copy();
        doc.SetDefaultTableStyle("Light List - Accent 4", false);
        Table table = doc.Tables.Add(tableRange, 3, 2);
        Object style = "Table Grid 1";
        table.set_Style(ref style);
        table.Cell(1, 1).Merge(table.Cell(1, 2));
        table.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = "Válaszok száma";
        table.Cell(1, 1).Range.Font.Bold = 2;
        table.Cell(2, 1).Range.Text = "This works lol";
        table.Cell(2, 2).Range.Text = "This works lol 2 2";
        table.Cell(3, 1).Range.Text = "This works lol";
        table.Cell(3, 2).Range.Text = "This works lol 2 2";
        table.Cell(4, 1).Range.Text = "This works lol";
        table.Cell(4, 2).Range.Text = "This works lol 2 2";
        table.Borders.OutsideLineWidth = WdLineWidth.wdLineWidth225pt;
    }
}
//     doc.InlineShapes.AddPicture(@"D:\programozás\OHV\OHV\OHV\bin\Debug\Capture.JPG", false, true);
doc.SaveAs2(@"D:\programozás\OHV\Doksi.docx");

Console.WriteLine("Exit");
try
{
    //Novacode.DocX docx = Novacode.DocX.Load(@"D:\programozás\OHV\Doksi.docx");
    //docx.SaveAs(@"D:\programozás\OHV\Doksi.pdf");
    doc.ExportAsFixedFormat(@"D:\programozás\OHV\Doksi.pdf",WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF);
    doc.Close();
    app.Quit();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: "I use C# 4.0 and Microsoft.Office.Interop for that."  The problem is much easier to debug with the C# code available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround for this.

I cut the excel chart I just made to the clipboard, then I paste it to the same place, then I wait for 2 seconds, and continue with the next chart.
The cut/paste seems to convert the chart to another type of word object, that is properly exported via pdf.

```
            wrdInlineShape.Range.Cut();
            shapeBookMark.Range.Paste();
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
```

(shapeBookMark was the original range where I have put the chart. The 2 seconds wait is needed because otherwise Word freezes with  an error message)